# Blender crashed and now when I try to open the file still crash!

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, objects, edges

I was duplicate a simple mesh with just edges and Blender crashed tried to reopen but recrash, tried to restart computer and still crash and now I have any auto save files showed, also the automatic backup file .blend1 crash.
I've tried to open the file with the 2.79 blender version but still crash.
I can append all object to a new file but is tedious.
Is there any other thing that I can try?

I have a backup but it's 3 days older!!! I can append new object on that file but still a little bit tedious remember and find the new objects

Blender Version 2.90.0 (2.90.0 2020-08-31)
Mac os 0.15.6 Catalina
Mac book pro 16""

here is the file [blender2.9 crash](https://www.dropbox.com/s/17lowbp7z0s480o/crash-blender29.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Press append,
look the scene up and append it, that will append everything into a new scene.
Before you do anything open a blender file tab, you delete the necessary objects from there.

[image]

Save the file and then switch from scene and hope it does not crash again

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand clearly, now I have open an older files that i backuped two days ago and I want try to append the new objects from there is it correct? Or is better if I try to append the entire scene on a new file? If yes, I click appned on new file and i append the entire scene? What you mean open a 'blender file tab'?

Comment: open a new blender file, append the scene, that will append everything. However as soon as you switch over to the new scene blender will crash, because you have too much meshes i think. Are there any meshes you don't mind deleting? See the image, that is a blender file tab, from there you can see the scene without opening it

Comment: Yes I have alot of meshes because I'm trying to improve some objects so I have alot of copies of those with different modifier and techniques, but yes I can delete most of them but I need to remember which ones. There's a way to check which objects are corrupted?

Comment: Ýou can create new scenes and then distribute your meshes over these scenes by dragging them over

Comment: I've tried and seems that it doubled some collections, now I have deleted all of them and also almost all of those useless object and it don't crash, now i gonna check if all is good thank you for yout support.

Comment: If i delete the double collections even if in the file tab it mantain contents objects when I switch to the new scen it crash, i don't delete the double i have double collections and if I then delete the objects just inside the doubled cllections it still crash. So I opened an old backup file and appended only the new objects created in the last two days and now it seems working (I hope). Thank you so much, in italian we say:" I lost 10 years of my life with this trouble!"